# How do I turn this unicode into a dict?

Tags: python, json, unicode

Sorry, I completely neglected to mention that I'm using Python. Let me try this again.

I'm using Python to consume a web service that returns the following JSON:

```
{
  "results" : [
    {
      "paramName" : "output",
      "dataType" : "GPString",
      "value" : "{'city': 'Falls Church', 'isRuralArea': False, 'zip': '22046', 'isNotInBTOPLMArea': True, 'longitude': '-77.186180', 'isGeocodable': True, 'county': u'Falls Church', 'isNotInBIPLMArea': True, 'state': 'VA', 'isLatLongInUSBounds': True, 'address': '604 Jackson St', 'latitude': '38.884937'}"
    }
  ],
  "messages" : [

  ]
}
```

Here are the important snippets from my fetching/parsing code:

```
import urllib
import httplib2
import json
import simplejson
http = httplib2.Http()

headers, response = http.request(url, 'GET')    

if headers['status'] == "200":

    responseAsJson = simplejson.loads(response)

    print "response = " + repr(responseAsJson)
    results = responseAsJson['results'][0]['value']
```

Unfortunately, this leaves me with the following value for *results* (as reported in PyScripter Debugger's Variables window):

```
u"{'city': 'Falls Church', 'isRuralArea': False, 'zip': '22046', 'isNotInBTOPLMArea': True, 'longitude': '-77.186180', 'isGeocodable': True, 'county': u'Falls Church', 'isNotInBIPLMArea': True, 'state': 'VA', 'isLatLongInUSBounds': True, 'address': '604 Jackson St', 'latitude': '38.884937'}"
```

I don't know how to then access the *address* or *city* keys, for instance.

Can you tell what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Thanks,
Jamie

---

**Old version of my question (obsolete):**

Here's the JSON I'm parsing:

```
response = {u'messages': [], u'results': [{u'dataType': u'GPString', u'value': u"{'city': 'Falls Church', 'isRuralArea': False, 'zip': '22046', 'isNotInBTOPLMArea': True, 'longitude': '-77.186180', 'isGeocodable': True, 'county': u'Falls Church', 'isNotInBIPLMArea': True, 'state': 'VA', 'isLatLongInUSBounds': True, 'address': '604 Jackson St', 'latitude': '38.884937'}", u'paramName': u'output'}]}
```

I've drilled down to this node, and its type is "unicode." How do I make a dict out of this? I think the fact that it's unicode is preventing me from creating the dict or accessing its keys, but I'm not sure.

```
u"{'city': 'Falls Church', 'isRuralArea': False, 'zip': '22046', 'isNotInBTOPLMArea': True, 'longitude': '-77.186180', 'isGeocodable': True, 'county': u'Falls Church', 'isNotInBIPLMArea': True, 'state': 'VA', 'isLatLongInUSBounds': True, 'address': '604 Jackson St', 'latitude': '38.884937'}"
```

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: This isn't a legitimate JSON string. I suspect you're using a language that is not in the tag list. What are you developing in, and what DBMS?

Comment: I created a service (in ArcGIS Geoprocessing Services), which returns some respectable looking JSON:
    **{"results":[{"paramName":"output","dataType":"GPString","value":"{'city': 'Falls Church', 'isRuralArea': False, 'zip': '22046', 'isNotInBTOPLMArea': True, 'longitude': '-77.186180', 'isGeocodable': True, 'county': u'Falls Church', 'isNotInBIPLMArea': True, 'state': 'VA', 'isLatLongInUSBounds': True, 'address': '604 Jackson St', 'latitude': '38.884937'}"}],"messages":[]}**

I get that with **headers, response = http.request(url, 'GET')** then **responseAsJson = simplejson.loads(response)**

Comment: Yes. the JSON from the service is legitimate, but the JSON in your original post is not. If you removed the `u` from the front of each attribute name, it would be legitimate.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my comment went off half-cocked. I'm still in the middle...

...Then, I do the following, which gives that "unicode" I mentioned: ***results = responseAsJson['results'][0]['value']***

Do you see what I've done wrong?

Comment: Please post your code. What language? Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `results` object looks like a string/unicode version of a dict, you need to eval it. A safe way of doing this (as of Python 2.6) would be to use the [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function:

```
results = ast.literal_eval(responseAsJson['results'][0]['value'])
```

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks! _results_ becomes a dict after evaluation.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. You should fix the JSON exporter in the server.

Comment: Hi jterrace, you'll see that (in the first code block of my original post) the server is returning proper JSON. It's not until I start parsing things out in Python that I end up with the unicode representation of a Python dict. I'm still not sure why that happens, but it's definitely happening on the client--not the server--side.

Answer (score 0):

This is not nearly a complete answer, since it's hard to tell what you're wanting. But a place to start is correcting the JSON string.

Here's the format of JSON you're probably wanting:

```
{'messages': [], 'results': [{'dataType': 'GPString', 'value': {'city': 'Falls Church', 'isRuralArea': False, 'zip': '22046', 'isNotInBTOPLMArea': True, 'longitude': '-77.186180', 'isGeocodable': True, 'county': 'Falls Church', 'isNotInBIPLMArea': True, 'state': 'VA', 'isLatLongInUSBounds': True, 'address': '604 Jackson St', 'latitude': '38.884937'}, 'paramName': 'output'}]}
```

I removed the `u` from the front of several attribute names and removed the surrounding `"` from the first attribute named `'value'`.

Now, in regard to your original question, we need more detail. Please post your code and what language/platform you're using? Guessing from the `responseAsJson()` mentioned in your comments, are you using RadAjax for ASP.NET? http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/ajax/ajxsimplewebserviceinvocation.html

Don't respond here, but instead edit it into your post.